# How to rewrite pointer after click OpenLayers?

Tags: openlayers, openlayers-2

I have a feature as point (icon). I try to modify it and recreate a point on the map with a new coordinates position by click.

```
this.modify = new Modify({
  hitDetection: this.vector,
  features: new Collection([feature]),
  style: []//overlayStyle,
});

const draw = new Draw();
```

How to do that?

I have found a solution to create a variable in service:

```
public editSinglePoint;
```

Then I listen changes in another service:

```
 this.map.on("click", (evt) => {
      if (this.drawingService.editSinglePoint) {
        this.drawingService.editSinglePoint
          .getGeometry()
          .setCoordinates(evt.coordinate);
      }
```

But I dislike this because it has smashed logic in code.